# R comparing 2 dfs to sum data between values

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes in R, one with start (column 1) and end (column 2) coordinates...

```
df1
2500    3499
3500    4499
4500    5499
5500    6499
```

And one with point coordinates (column 1) and associated values (column 2)...

```
df2
2657    17
2895    33
3875    12
4448    42
5122    3
5633    65
5781    12
```

I would like to find a vectorized approach to sum the values from df2 column 2 where df2 column 1 coordinates are between the start and stop coordinates for df1. with this data the result should look like this...

```
df3
2500    3499    50
3500    4499    54
4500    5499    3
5500    6499    77
```

The dfs contain 100,000+ rows, I can achieve this easily using loops, but as were are in R it is slow and not the best approach.

What is the best way to do this? Also a flexible solution that can be adapted to other functions, other than simply summing data would be good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table::foverlaps` solution. As you haven't specified column names, I'm assuming that they are called `V1` and `V2` in both data sets

---

**Solution**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, `:=`(start = V1, end = V2)] 
setDT(df2)[, `:=`(start = V1, end = V1)]
setkey(df1, start, end)
foverlaps(df2, df1)[, list(SumV2 = sum(i.V2)), by = list(V1, V2)]
#      V1   V2 SumV2
# 1: 2500 3499    50
# 2: 3500 4499    54
# 3: 4500 5499     3
# 4: 5500 6499    77
```

---

**Explanation**

Here we converted both data sets to `data.table` objects and specified the `start/end` values to overlap on. Then, we keyed the data set that we want to join against. Finally we ran the `foverlaps` function and then aggregated the matched values of `V2` from `df2` by the desired columns in `df1`

---

**Data**

```
df1  <- structure(list(V1 = c(2500L, 3500L, 4500L, 5500L), V2 = c(3499L, 
4499L, 5499L, 6499L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(2657L, 2895L, 3875L, 4448L, 5122L, 5633L, 
5781L), V2 = c(17L, 33L, 12L, 42L, 3L, 65L, 12L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks that works nicely. I had to update R as setDT does not work for version 2.15. Also took me a while to spot your error in line 5: sum(i.V2) should be sum(V2). As an extension to this question, if df1 has more columns and these need to be preserved, and, if rows which sum to zero also need to be preserved, how would you do that?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming you are working with an R version from this decade :). Also `i.V2` isn't an error. Other then that, it would be easier if you'd make your example more reproducible with a real column names and values that won't match and your desired output.

Comment: interesting, it gives me the error "object 'i.V2' not found", when using the example here. when I remove the "i." everything works. can you explain more?

Comment: `i.V2` is the column `V2` from `df2`. Just `V2` is the `V2` column from `df1`. As I said, if you'd have meaningful column names it would be easier to reproduce

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now, got i.V2 to work without the error. Many thanks.